# key error when deleting comma in .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Data: [Github_Link](https://github.com/610yilingliu/MGMT5504/tree/master/Data)

The dataframe looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to delete commas in the first row(there are some stuff like '1,000')

but there is a key error:'Price'

Code:

```
import pandas

def main():
    df=pandas.read_csv("Rent_Message.csv",index_col=0)
    df=df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1)
    df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(",").astype(float)
main()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: what is the content of the CSV file?

Comment: @kampangala That's in their link, though it would be better to include some representative data in the question. OP: Please also show the output of `print(df.columns)`

Comment: have you check properly if it key error or TypeError. One error that I can figure out is relplace function requires atleast two parameters and you have given one. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are that column as the index before replacing the string. Also, you aren't replacing the comma with anything as str.replace takes 2 arguments, lastly return df

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.read_csv("Rent_message.csv") # don't set index, you can do it later.
    df = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1) # this line is okay
    df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(",", '').astype(float) # fix str.replace
    df.set_index('Price', inplace=True)
    return df
main()
```

output:

```
df.head()
         Postcode Type_Property  Num_Bedroom  Num_Bathroom  Num_Carspace  \
Price                                                                      
550.0    8/2/1916         house            4             2             2   
350.0    7/1/1916         house            3             1             5   
450.0   11/6/1916         house            4             2             2   
300.0   7/10/1916         house            4             2             2   
400.0   7/30/1916         house            4             1             2   
300.0    7/1/1916          unit            2             1             2   
200.0        6017     apartment            2             1             1   
950.0        6004     apartment            3             2             2   
1500.0       6151     apartment            4             3             1
```

Comment: df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(",","").astype(float) # fix str.replace

Comment: there should be a comma in replace, a tiny problem ^_^

Comment: Good catch! Sorry about that, that's what I get for retyping the code instead of just pasting it :P, I edited the answer to include the comma.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by d_kennetz, `Price` is your index column. You can either follow his approach and sets the index at a later stage, or you can use this snippet instead to replace the index values

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(",","").astype(float)
```